# Wordpress make Grandparent and great grandparent filterable in custom columns

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

Is there a way to make a Custom Post Type's grandparent and great grandparent filterable in the CPT's columns?

For parents I use :

```
esc_url( add_query_arg( 'post_type' => $post->post_type, 'post_parent' => $parentID , 'edit.php' ) )enter code here
```

But this wont work for the Grandparent of the CPT.

I tryed several relative solutions (like child_of, post_parent__in) found here but with no luck.

Any suggestions on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading through the codex, I came across the `pre_get_posts` hook, and I decided to try changing the query with it, which worked for me. Not sure if it is the best way though.

For anyone that is interested here is what I did:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'get_grandchildren' );

function get_grandchildren() {
    if ( isset( $_GET['child_of'] ) ) {
        //Make a custom loop which selects the id of grandchildren of parents and puts them in an array and then
        set_query_var('post__in', $childrenArray );
    }
}
```